# Small bug with click-to-scroll menu in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have set up a "click-to-scroll" menu with the logic of:

`1. when menu link is clicked, scroll to corresponding anchor and add active class to $(this)`

`2. onscroll, toggle active class according to the current anchor's location`

This all works fine, but there is a small bug in that when you click a link, the page flickers slightly and so do the active menu links. You can see and test it live at http://jcwd98.appspot.com/ (warning that it's in its early development stages, no mobile and probably looks pretty crappy right now).

I'm not sure what causes the page to flicker, but I do know that the reason the menu links flicker is because my code is telling it to add an active class to it when it scrolls over its corresponding section. Since the document has to first scroll over a section to get to the desired section, it adds an active class to other links before it arrives.

I don't want either of these scenarios.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve5qr3bL/1/)

Code:

```js
var section_padding = 45;

$("#menu ul li a").on("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault;

 $("#menu ul li a.active").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");

 var target = this.hash;
 var menu = target;
 var cache_target = $(target);
 var buffer = (cache_target.offset().top - section_padding);

 $("html, body").stop().animate({
  "scrollTop": buffer
 }, 400, "swing");

});

function scroll(event) {
 var scroll_pos = $(document).scrollTop();
 $("#menu ul li a").each(function() {
  var cur_link = $(this);
  var ref_el = $(cur_link.attr("href"));

  if( ref_el.position().top <= scroll_pos && ref_el.position().top + ref_el.height() + (section_padding * 2) > scroll_pos ) {
   $("#menu ul li a").removeClass("active");
   cur_link.addClass("active");
  } else {
   cur_link.removeClass("active");
  }

 });
}

$(document).on("scroll", scroll);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

#menu ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 5);
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
}

#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li a.active {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

#sections {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

section {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #67D182;
    padding: 45px 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sections section:nth-child(even) {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sections">
    <section id="top">
      <h2>#top</h2>  
    </section>
    
    <section id="about">
      <h2>#about</h2>  
    </section>
    
    <section id="portfolio">
      <h2>#portfolio</h2>  
    </section>
    
    <section id="contact">
      <h2>#contact</h2>  
    </section>
    
    <section id="blog">
      <h2>#blog</h2>  
    </section>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because `preventDefault` is a function, then you only need to change:

```
event.preventDefault;
```

To:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

And this work fine.
FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ve5qr3bL/2/

**EDIT:**

You need to `unbind` the scroll event, and then `bind` it again when the animation be completed.

```
$("#menu ul li a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(document).off("scroll"); // here unbind

    // code

    $("html, body").stop().animate({
        "scrollTop": buffer
    }, 400, "swing", function() {
        $(document).on("scroll", scroll); // here bind again
    });

});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ve5qr3bL/3/

Comment: Well that fixes the page's flicker, but it still doesn't fix the problem with the active class on the menu links. +1 for the partial fix.

Comment: If I add `$(document).scroll("off")` the menu link problem goes away, but then the toggle class on scroll doesn't work.